# How to make VBA code run for a specific Excel file?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble finding the error: what I want to do is to make this code run on Sheet1 of Book1.xls ONLY, even when I work in other excel file or other sheets of this file. All works fine for first part of the code until ******-line but afterwards when I am on a different  page or file it "chokes" and give me an error.

```
    Sub Upload0()

' Upload Webpage content
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Upload0"
With Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://cetatenie.just.ro/ordine/articol-11", Destination:=Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
    .Name = "CetatenieOrdine"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

' Deletes Empty Cells
Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp

******************************************************************************

' Deletes useless Rows and fits the Width
Rows("1:31").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B28").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Rows("17:309").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


' Text to Column function with auto-confirmation to overwrite
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Columns("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Columns("B:B").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft


' fit the Width of All Columns
Cells.Select
Range("A37").Activate
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("H1").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Font.bold = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access `Rows` or `Range` without specifying a sheet, VBA uses ActiveSheet. In this case you should explicitly specify the sheet you want to work with:

```
Sub Upload0()

' Upload Webpage content
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Upload0"
With Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://cetatenie.just.ro/ordine/articol-11", Destination:=Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
    .Name = "CetatenieOrdine"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

' Deletes Empty Cells
Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp

******************************************************************************
With Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Deletes useless Rows and fits the Width
    .Rows("1:31").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .Rows("17:309").Delete Shift:=xlUp


    ' Text to Column function with auto-confirmation to overwrite
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Columns("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
            :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    .Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar _
            :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Columns("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft


    ' fit the Width of All Columns
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows("1:1").Font.bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is still a problem, for instance for simplcity I use the With...end with clause for the portion only that you have above it still considers the Activesheet for some reason.Any clue?

Comment: How do you know that? It doesn't delete selection on Book1!Sheet1 worksheet?

Comment: Well, if I take the code from beginning to this part where you posted and add also WITH clasue and End it does it properly only if I stay on Sheet1, moving to other page leads to the code to execute only the DELETING part that you have above without downloading, pasting....etc. Maybe you can try, does it work well for you?

Comment: I got it, I was missing the inner . to make reference to With Clause. May I ask you if get an error with respect to first SELECT clasue right after starting your WTH?

Comment: Try to do all your stuff without Select methods. It doesn't seem working if you invoke it from another sheet. See my updated code.